# Why is only one page responsive?

Tags: mobile, responsive

On our blog, only one page is responsive. All other pages are not reorganized when they we access them. I checked all of the settings and searched the web for a while but I could not find a hint about why this happens.

Here's the page that works:  http://blog.tryd.com.br/archives/4494

Any other page looks wrong on cell phones.

Any ideas of why is it happening?

Comment: Better aimed at theme's developers/support.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the `div` with `id` of `wrapper` has it's width set in the CSS.

It should have `width` of `auto`.

I can see that the page that works (the one you provided a link for), the `body` has a `class` under which the `div` width `id` `wrapper` has it's `width` set to `auto`.

```
@media (max-width: 1100px){
    body.mobile #wrapper, 
    body.mobile #colophon, body.mobile #main, 
    body.mobile article.post, body.mobile #container, body.mobile #linky{
      width: auto;
    }
}
```

Actually, I can see that there are several elements that have their width set to auto, when `body` has the `class` `mobile`.

All other pages - `body` does not have the `class` mobile.

To answer your question in general, a `block` element will need it's `width` set to `auto` or `100%` or just not have it's `width` set in CSS (natural width is 100%).

For your situation specifically, you need to give the `body` the class `mobile` on all pages:

```
<body class="mobile">
```

The quickest way will probably be to edit the `body` that in `header.php`.

Next quickest, but probably the 'cleaner' way, is to use the body class filter (put this in your theme's `functions.php`, replacing 'my_theme' with your theme's directory's name):

```
add_filter('body_class', 'my_theme_body_classes');

function my_theme_body_classes($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'mobile';
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: ... But, yeah, this question is probably better placed in stackoverflow.com, as it is a generic CSS question, rather than specifically WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

On the site that works responsively you have the stylesheet`dcd6b.css` which handles the responsive look of your website. On all the other pages it is missing. Enqueue `dcd6b.css` and it should work.

Comment: The CSS required is in `5d70a.css` which is included in the pages that aren't currenlty being responsive. The problem is that the `body` does not have the required class `mobile`.

Comment: Yes, but `5d70a.css` doesn't have the media query `@media (max-width: 1100px)` which sets the width to `auto`.

Comment: @Dan you are right. Adding the class `mobile` to the `body` will fix the problem.

Comment: You're also correct, sorry I didn't see that `@media (max-width: 1100px)` isn't in that CSS file. But yeah, adding `mobile` class to `body` does fix it. Must be other CSS somewhere in that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  As suggested, I searched on the theme's support forum and found a hint there that led me to the solution. It had something to do with the CSS minifier plugin and page caching.  I cleared the cache and the mobile pages are back to normal.